# Getting java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android

I know a there are lots of people have asked this same thing but I just don't know what's going on. I'm trying to make function like [this](https://lh3.ggpht.com/W89eqMvqowxOi0jG4Z_we86NNy3lVzatqRILC6zdmboXkaAP3QRVcdht1ulkf0BvR3Ev)
which consists of 2 `EditText`s, 2 `ListView`s and 1 button. For my apps, user will put input inside `EditText` (1 for user location and another 1 for destination) the purpose I include `ListView` is when the user enter input 1 or 2 letters, the listView show suggestion of the places regarding the letters. However, the `ListView` is hidden - it only will show the list whenever the user have put input inside the `EditText`.

My code didn't show any errors, but when I run logCat gives me this:

```
07-02 15:57:39.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5545): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 15:57:39.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5545): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.series3/com.example.series3.FindMePlace}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-02 15:57:39.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
07-02 15:57:39.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-02 15:57:39.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-02 15:57:39.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-02 15:57:39.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-02 15:57:39.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-02 15:57:39.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-02 15:57:39.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 15:57:39.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-02 15:57:39.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-02 15:57:39.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-02 15:57:39.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-02 15:57:39.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5545): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-02 15:57:39.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at com.example.series3.FindMePlace.onCreate(FindMePlace.java:80)
07-02 15:57:39.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-02 15:57:39.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
07-02 15:57:39.160: E/AndroidRuntime(5545):     ... 11 more
```

seriously i really have no ideas where i'm wrong. please help me solve this problem
here is my code:

**FindMePlace.java**

```
public class FindMePlace extends Activity {

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Declaration
    public static UkmRoute selectedPath = null;
    final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    private EditText filterText = null;
    private EditText filterText2 = null;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;
    final ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayList<String> results_id = new ArrayList<String>();
    Button search;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.findmeplace);
        // final Intent c = new Intent(FindMePlace.this,
        // QSLocationDetail.class);

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Link editText to layout item
        filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_Location);
        filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
        filterText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_Destination);
        filterText2.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

        /*populateFromLocation();
        populateToDestination();*/

            // Reading location
            Log.d("Reading", "Reading all location ..");
            List<UkmRoute> location = db.getAllUKMRoute();

            for (UkmRoute k : location) {
                results.add(k.getFromLocation());
                results_id.add(k.getID());
            }
            // Set list arrayAdapter to adapter
            if (!filterText.getText().toString().equals(""))
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(FindMePlace.this,
                        R.layout.list_item, R.id.textView1, results);
            else {
                ArrayList<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(FindMePlace.this,
                        R.layout.list_item, R.id.textView1, r);
            }

            // adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,
            // R.id.textView1, results);
            setListAdapter(adapter);

            // Set ListView from ListActivity
            ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Log.d("test", "position:" + position);

                    Log.d("test",
                            "actualname:"
                                    + db.getUkmRouteByFrom(
                                            adapter.getItem(position))
                                            .getFromLocation());

                    // String poiID = results_id.get(position);
                    String poiID = db.getUkmRouteByFrom(adapter.getItem(position))
                            .getID();
                    setSelectedPoi(poiID);
                    // startActivity(c);

                }
            });
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                List<UkmRoute> destination = db.getAllUKMRoute();
                for (UkmRoute k : destination) {
                    results.add(k.getToDestination());
                    results_id.add(k.getID());
                }
                if (!filterText2.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(FindMePlace.this,
                            R.layout.list_item, R.id.textView1, results);
                else {
                    ArrayList<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();
                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(FindMePlace.this,
                            R.layout.list_item, R.id.textView1, r);
                }
                setListAdapter(adapter);

                // Set ListView from ListActivity
                ListView lv2 = getListView();
                lv2.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

                // Set click event from listView
                lv2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                        // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Log.d("test", "position:" + position);

                        Log.d("test",
                                "actualname:"
                                        + db.getUkmRouteByTo(adapter.getItem(position))
                                                .getFromLocation());

                        // String poiID = results_id.get(position);
                        String poiID = db.getUkmRouteByTo(adapter.getItem(position))
                                .getID();
                        setSelectedPoi(poiID);
                        // startActivity(c);

                    }
                });

    }

    // Initiate database data
        public void initiateDb() {
            DatabaseHandler myDbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);

            try {
                myDbHandler.createDataBase();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                throw new Error("Unable to create database");
            }

            try {
                myDbHandler.openDataBase();
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                throw sqle;
            }
            Log.d("Initiate",
                    "UKM Route Count: " + myDbHandler.getUkmRouteCount());
            myDbHandler.close();
        }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    private ListView getListView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private void setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            if (!filterText.getText().toString().equals(""))
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(FindMePlace.this,
                        R.layout.list_item, R.id.textView1, results);
            else {
                ArrayList<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(FindMePlace.this,
                        R.layout.list_item, R.id.textView1, r);
            }
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        filterText.removeTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
    }

    public UkmRoute getSelectedPoi() {
        return selectedPath;
    }

    public void setSelectedPoi(String ID_route) {
        selectedPath = db.getUkmRoute(ID_route);
        Log.d("test2", "ID_route:" + db.getUkmRoute(ID_route).getID());
        Log.d("test2", "FromLocation:" + db.getUkmRoute(ID_route).getFromLocation());
        // kene buat if else ke kalau nk tmbah part Destination?
        // Closing db
        db.close();
    }


}
```

**findmeplace.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".FindMePlace" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_Destination"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/search_box"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/edittext_hint1"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_Location"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="138dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/edittext_hint"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/search_box"
        android:layout_marginBottom="71dp"
        android:text="@string/searchbutton" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/inputLocation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/search_Location"
        android:layout_below="@+id/search_Location"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >
    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/inputDestination"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/search_Destination"
        android:layout_below="@+id/search_Destination"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**list_item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

Comment: what's line 80 in FindMePlace.java?

Comment: this is line 80

lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

Comment: extend `ListActivity`. Also show us xml code.

Comment: alright. i already update the question by adding the xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your listview is not initialized.

```
      ListView lv = getListView(); // lv is null
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

**ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen**. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate(). **To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)**

If you extend ListActivity you can have single listview.

```
     <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Your class does not extend `ListActivtiy`. Make sure you extend `ListActivity`

If you extend `Activity` you should do the below

```
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.inputLocation); 
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Also you have methods as below which does nothing and should be removed.

```
private ListView getListView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

private void setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: yah. i know.i read from lots of website, when we did multiple listview, i should use Activity instead of ListActivity.

Comment: multiple listview? i din't understand what you are trying to tell. setListAdapter is method of `ListActivity`

Comment: i mean i have two listview for 1 activity

Comment: @riehime23 when using `getListView()` you can't have two lists.. How can the computer know what list you mean?

Comment: you are getting confused i guess. Activity does not have `setListAdapter` and you can't initialize Listview as `lv= getListView()` if you extend activity. if you extend activity initialize like `ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.inputLocation)` and set adapter to lsitview as `lv.setAdapter(adapter)`.

Comment: i think so,i'm confused. by the way, i works. but why my when i put input 1 or 2 letters, the list view didn't showing out?

Comment: @riehime23 you get a exception that is what logcat says. its a nullpointerexception and the application has crashed.

Comment: when i delete the method private void setListAdapter, i have errors at setListAdapter(adapter);

Comment: @riehime23 of course you will have errors coz you extend `Activity` not `ListActivity` and `Activity` does not have a method `setListAdapter`.

Comment: @riehime23 check the first link in the answer posted.

Comment: so i also have to delete setListAdapter(adapter); without any replacement?

Comment: @riehime23 first decide whether you need to extend Activity or ListActivity. Based on that check the docs for the api methods and use the same. Activity does not have `setListAdapter`. If you extend `Activity` then initialize listview as ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.inputLocation) and then setAdapteto listview as `lv.setAdapter(adapter)`.

Comment: how bout the setAdapter inside method public void onTextChanged? i got error there.

Comment: @riehime23 you are getting confused again. i don't know how i can explain further. please check the docs for `Activtiy`, `ListActivity` and `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

Your getListView() method returns hardcoded null. Leading to the NPE one line below for setTextFilterEnabled

Answer (score 0):

You haven't extended `ListActivity`, thus you can't use `getListView()`..

You should find it by `id` when you don't extend `ListActivity`.
if your list has the `id` equal to `list` then:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

By the way it can have any `id`..

I think `ListActivity` kind of makes you limited to only the id `list`.. I don't like that behavior.

However `ListActivity` has some good methods to work with lists, but I like `Activity` better...